# SQL lookup / loop in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a mapping between existing job positions and new job positions. Unfortunately, there is no mapping between the new / old position. Hence, I thought I could lookup between the Activities and the one with the best fit would be the right one.

Background:

Im running an MySQL DB with five tables, Table A is listing all the employees. Table B shows all the positions with a type wheter it is a new or an old position. Table C lists all existing activities.
Table D & E are mapping between Position <-> Activities and Employee <-> Position (old), but I dont have a mapping between the old and new positions.

I have following tables:

```
TABLE A (Employee, Name)
TABLE B (Position, Description, Type (new/old) )
TABLE C (Activities, Description)
TABLE D (Position, Activities)
TABLE E (Employee, Position)
```

As a final outcome, I need to create a list with the Employee to new position mapping.
Dont know if this is possible with SQL only as i guess it needs to loop to find the best matching new position

EDIT:
The expected result for the Employees (John Doe, Celine Dion) is to get the ITSM role (with Type N) as there is ab better match (two Activities) than ITPM as it matches only by one Activity

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE r2e.Employee
(
    fUID Char(15),
    fName Char (255),
    PRIMARY KEY(fUID)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE r2e.Position
(
    fPosition Char (15),
    fPDescription Char (255),
    fPType Char(1),
    PRIMARY KEY(fPosition)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE r2e.Activities
(
    fActivity Char(15),
    fADescription Char (255),
    PRIMARY KEY(fActivity)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE r2e.P2A
(
    fPosition Char(15),
    fActivity Char (15),
    PRIMARY KEY(fPosition,fActivity)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE r2e.E2P
(
    fUID Char(15),
    fPosition Char (15),
    PRIMARY KEY(fUID,fPosition)
);

INSERT INTO r2e.Employee (fUID,fName) VALUES ('U8001','Peter Meyer'),('U8002','John Doe'),('U8003','Paul Pott'),('U8004','Celine Dion');
INSERT INTO r2e.Position (fPosition,fPDescription,fPType) VALUES ('ITM','IT Manager','O'),('ITCM','IT Compliance Manager','O'),('CEO','CEO of the company','O'),('ITSM','IT Service Manager','N'),('ITPM','IT Project Manager','N');
INSERT INTO r2e.Activities (fActivity,fADescription) VALUES ('C0012','Create Order'),('C0013','Negotiate with Supplier'),('C0015','Sign Contract'),('C0016','Create Dunning letter'),('C0017','Cancel Invoice'),('C0018','Cancel Order');
INSERT INTO r2e.P2A (fPosition,fActivity) VALUES ('ITM','C0012'),('ITM','C0015'),('ITM','C0017'),('ITSM','C0017'),('ITSM','C0012'),('CEO','C0017'),('CEO','C0018'),('ITPM','C0017');
INSERT INTO r2e.E2P (fUID,fPosition) VALUES ('U8004','ITM'),('U8001','CEO'),('U8002','ITM'),('U8003','ITCM');
```

Comment: Provide tables as CREATE TABLE. Add some sample data as INSERT INTO and desired output for this data, with explanations.

Comment: Added a samples and expected results.

Comment: Look at the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c91b8d836f956257a2e12f92b72606b7). I have tried to show the logic, step-by-step. Check it.

Comment: Thanks, Im running this against the database now ... but with a lot of more data. After 5h still running....